# Converting boolean to 1's and 0's in Azure Data Factory

Tags: boolean, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON file which contains a boolean and what I wanted to know was whether it's actually possible to convert these TRUE and FALSE's to 1's and 0's within the pipeline?

[image]

Any help or information will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can convert these  via *Direved Column* in data flow.

Comment: Thanks! Solved it. You should write it as an answer so that it can get accepted as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert these TRUE and FALSE's to 1's and 0's via **Direved Column** in data flow.